# Button that is attached to the particular part of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I want to add a button that is attached  to the particular part of the screen. It means that when I scroll my TableView, the position of this button on the screen doesn't change. I want my screen to look exactly like [this](http://i-fotki.info/22/997a29bde5055612606901fc0399922605e47d284086353.jpg.html) or [this](http://i-fotki.info/22/95ef33a21ab3b71fd1f2cbd7a17a6e3505e47d284086353.jpg.html) app.

I would be grateful for any help. Thank you!

Comment: I think that for this purpose you can add the button to navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add global Button then use.

```
class func addGlobalButton() {

    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

    //Create Button Frame
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.width - 90, y: bounds.height - 150, width: 80, height: 80))

    //For Circular button
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 40

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(button)
}

class func buttonClicked() {
  print("Button Clicked")
}
```

Put this function in app delegate and call once in any view controller as :

```
AppDelegate.addGlobalButton()
```

Comment: check the answer if you don't have navigation controller

Comment: Sorry, but where button should appear? After implementation I can't see it. I don't have nav controller, by I can embed in one, if it is needed

Comment: Does this make the button to appear above vc in all vc's ?

Comment: Yes it make button appear on all vc's

Comment: Currently I am using only one view for this purpose, so the case with navigation bar is easier now. I really appreciate your help :) 
If I will decide to use your approach hereafter, the question is: 
I implemented this code in app delegate, but I can't call it in my ViewController: "Instance member 'addGlobalButton' cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?" I put it in my ViewDidLoad

Comment: Please check updated answer because i change function as class level, now it not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 99, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 88/255, blue: 171/255, alpha: 1)
button.tintColor = .white
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
button.setTitle("Search", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(search), for: .touchUpInside)

self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(button)
```

This code makes a button and puts it in navigation controller which is above your table view

Comment: Well, I understand now. But what if I don't have tab bar? How to attach this button to the bottom of the view?

Comment: What is your situation?

Comment: This is my [Storyboard](http://i-fotki.info/22/b168f5c493933169101ee43657a46376059fe5284089332.png.html) and [simulator](http://i-fotki.info/22/cb855ca3ef31eecb5178cfac2a303670059fe5284089332.png.html) screenshots, if you mean that.

Comment: So you can use this code because you have navigation controller